# Item selection in NavigationView

Tags: uwp, navigationview

In NavigationView I have 3 Items. If user click on the second button I would like to clean form and redirect (for example with MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));) to the first Item. Redirect works fine but NavigationViewItem's selection stay on the second NavigationViewItem.
The same code:

```
nvTopLevelNav.SelectedItem = nvTopLevelNav.MenuItems[index];
(nvTopLevelNav.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem).IsSelected = true;
```

does not help. Is there any way to change selection?

By the way, if for navigation I use MainPage (MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));) I will get the second Menu with correct selection. For me it looks like object is not correct refreshed. Could you please clarify?

Comment: The first line of code should be sufficient to set the selected item properly. If `MenuItems[index]` is the item you want to set as selected, it should surely work. Could you post some additional code (XAML, etc.) to help us understand what is happening?

Comment: I uploaded the project [link](https://files.fm/u/32xb7vee)

Comment: I have checked the code, where are you actually setting the `SelectedItem`? I can't find any instance. For example when inside of the `switch` - `case "Nav_BlankPage2":` I would just do `nvTopLevelNav.SelectedItem = nvTopLevelNav.MenuItems[1];` after the `Navigate` call. Also it seems you are navigating to `BlankPage1` in this case, I would expect navigation to `BlankPage2`. That doesn't work for you?

Comment: It does not work. My idea is: the first page is the main, the second button should work like "Clean" the first page and sound like "New Page". As I mentioned, navigation works ok, but menu save the selection of the clicked Button. Is there any way to change NavigationViewItem selection manually?

Comment: The one I describe is the way how you set it manually, so I don't know what's wrong. I will check back when I am at my PC

Comment: Could you tell me why you want to set the seleted item to be another item you doesn't selected on the UI? It is not a best practice, may be we can have other scenario to achieve it.

Comment: for example,  the first tab is My Auto and the second is New Auto. User may edit existing Auto and if he would like to have new one, click New Auto. He will be redirected to the My Auto with clear data. Sure it maybe implementel like a button "New Auto" on the "My Auto" tab but I would like to have "New Auto" like a tab.

Comment: The NavigationView force the selected item to be the one User select. If you insist to use this similar UI, you can try to use the [Split view control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/split-view), it is more flexible.

Comment: Breeze Liu - thank you a lot its one of the way to resolve it but if i understand right, in that case i have to implement the same functionality by hands (at least some of it). Currently i have a problem only with mark on the tab. Everything works fine. Is there any way to use styles or resources or maybe some debug tools to check this option? Sorry I am brand new in it.

Comment: Breeze Liu - If you have time, please take a look at the project: [link](https://ufile.io/2cvxq). If you click on the "Nav_BlankPage2" (str 53 in MainPage.xaml.cs), the pointer jump to the "Nav_BlankPage1" and after that back. The code is really simple. I have not idea how to check it and what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview)'s `Tapped` event to change its [SelectedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.selecteditem#Microsoft_UI_Xaml_Controls_NavigationView_SelectedItem). See the following code.

Xaml:

```xml
<NavigationView x:Name="nvTopLevelNav" Tapped="nvTopLevelNav_Tapped" .../>
```

Code Behind:

```cs
private void nvTopLevelNav_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(nvTopLevelNav.SelectedItem);
    NavigationViewItem ItemContent = nvTopLevelNav.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem;
    if (ItemContent != null)
    {
        switch (ItemContent.Tag)
        {
            case "Nav_BlankPage1":
                MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));

                break;
            case "Nav_BlankPage2":
                MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
                MyItem = nvTopLevelNav.MenuItems.ElementAt(0) as NavigationViewItem;
                nvTopLevelNav.SelectedItem = MyItem;
                break;
            case "Nav_BlankPage3":
                MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage3));
                break;
            case "Nav_Settings":
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `SelectedItem` using the `Dispatcher` has worked for me:

```
Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
    MainNavigationView.SelectedItem = MenuItem_Home;
});
```

The `RunAsync` method is used to execute code on the UI thread, but it can be called from the UI thread too.